# Blackberry vendor account still disabled

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-world

I have registered for the blackberry vendor account since April 2013. Few days ago I received a reply email said that Blackberry can not identify my account.

To be honest, it is a pain. I provided them my passport including my full name and dob. It takes too long and now the result is.......

Anybody have any idea how to register the BB vendor account. Normally, how long does it take? I already made many BB10 apps and just waiting for this verification so that I can publish them to the BB market.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a change on the BlackBerry App World lately. The BlackBerry World Vendor Portal has been updated to use BlackBerry ID.

If you have an existing Vendor Portal account, you'll be able to link it to your BlackBerry ID. You can sign in to the Vendor Portal through your BlackBerry ID. [This](https://appworld.blackberry.com/isvportal/home.do?retCode=MA==&type=bG9nb3V0c3Nv) link should be useful.

Comment: Hi Sarah, I know that these two account linked together. Nevertheless, I am registering for the vendor account as I haven't had it yet. Cheers,

Comment: But you can use your BlackBerry ID instead. Why wait for the vendor account?

Comment: BB Id can not be used to upload app, according to my knowledge. But anyway, I emailed them again and I received my vendor account yesterday. Now I am happily waiting for publishing some of my first apps. Thanks.